# Repeat the value in column until a change occurs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Location': ['ALABAMA', 'Auburn', 'Florence', 'Jacksonville', 'ALASKA', 'Fairbanks'], 'State': ['ALABAMA', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'ALASKA', np.nan]})

       Location    State
0       ALABAMA  ALABAMA
1        Auburn      NaN
2      Florence      NaN
3  Jacksonville      NaN
4        ALASKA   ALASKA
5     Fairbanks      NaN
```

What I want is to replace the NaN values in the 'State' column with their corresponding state name. In other words, repeat the value in column until a change occurs. This is the desired output:

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Location': ['ALABAMA', 'Auburn', 'Florence', 'Jacksonville', 'ALASKA', 'Fairbanks'], 'State': ['ALABAMA', 'ALABAMA', 'ALABAMA', 'ALABAMA', 'ALASKA', 'ALASKA']})

       Location    State
0       ALABAMA  ALABAMA
1        Auburn  ALABAMA
2      Florence  ALABAMA
3  Jacksonville  ALABAMA
4        ALASKA   ALASKA
5     Fairbanks   ALASKA
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and avoid pictures of data.

Comment: Sorry, I was in hurry. I already changed it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your top dataframe image is what you have already then this is a simple problem.

```
df['State'].fillna(method='ffill')
```