# Switch consecutive values in column until condition changes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to compare two values (this can be two columns or even two random values), the result of said comparison will be used to fill values in a pandas column. The comparison itself is not a problem, and can be done using `np.where`. But my goal is to have a conditional switch. For example, if the comparision results in true, than all the values until comparision again becomes true will be X. In case the condition becomes true again, the values to be filled will switch to Y, followed by X in case of another true....until all comparisons are done.
Similar to this: [Repeat the value in column until a change occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345605/repeat-the-value-in-column-until-a-change-occurs)

Minimum working example to create dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, .01, size=(100, 1)),
                  columns=list('A'))
df['condition'] = np.where(df['A'] > np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.5),
                           'Switch', 'DoNotSwitch')

print df

           A    condition
0   0.004392  DoNotSwitch
1   0.002493  DoNotSwitch
2   0.007735  DoNotSwitch
3   0.000523  Switch
4   0.009902  DoNotSwitch
5   0.001712  DoNotSwitch
6   0.006146  DoNotSwitch
7   0.005325  Switch
8   0.003555  DoNotSwitch
9   0.003444  DoNotSwitch
10  0.005225  DoNotSwitch
11  0.000619  DoNotSwitch
```

What I want is:

```
           A    condition    Result
0   0.004392  DoNotSwitch    T
1   0.002493  DoNotSwitch    T
2   0.007735  DoNotSwitch    T
3   0.000523  Switch         F
4   0.009902  DoNotSwitch    F
5   0.001712  DoNotSwitch    F
6   0.006146  DoNotSwitch    F
7   0.005325  Switch         T
8   0.003555  DoNotSwitch    T
9   0.003444  DoNotSwitch    T
10  0.005225  DoNotSwitch    T
11  0.000619  DoNotSwitch    T
```

Is there a way to condense `np.where` and the generation of `Result` column in one single step, since the `condition` column just indicates where the switch should happen and itself is not necessary ?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC,

```
s = df['condition'].eq('Switch')

df['result'] = np.where(s.cumsum() % 2 == 0,
                        'T', 'F')
```

Note that `s` here is exactly your condition:

```
df['A'] > np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.5)
```

So you can bypass the construction of `df['condition']` like this:

```
s = df['A'] > np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.5)
df['result'] = np.where(s.cumsum() % 2 == 0, 'T', 'F')
```

Output:

```
           A    condition result
0   0.004392  DoNotSwitch      T
1   0.002493  DoNotSwitch      T
2   0.007735  DoNotSwitch      T
3   0.000523       Switch      F
4   0.009902  DoNotSwitch      F
5   0.001712  DoNotSwitch      F
6   0.006146  DoNotSwitch      F
7   0.005325       Switch      T
8   0.003555  DoNotSwitch      T
9   0.003444  DoNotSwitch      T
10  0.005225  DoNotSwitch      T
11  0.000619  DoNotSwitch      T
```

Answer (score 1):

Switching a boolean `old_value` conditional on another boolean `switch` can be written using `XOR`:

```
new_value = old_valaue ^ switch
```

To do it sequentially we can use the `accumulate` attribute of `np.bitwise_xor`:

```
# create random switch points with 20% probability
switches = np.random.random(20) < 0.2
values = np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(switches)

# display them side by side
np.c_[switches,values]
# array([[False, False],
#        [False, False],
#        [ True,  True],
#        [False,  True],
#        [False,  True],
#        [False,  True],
#        [ True, False],
#        [False, False],
#   ...
```

This is almost what we want only it starts on the wrong side. The easiest remedy would be to simply flip the result:

```
values ^= start_value
```

Alternatively, for very long sequences it may be more econonimcal to switch only the first element of `switches`

```
switches[0] ^= start_value
values = np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(switches)
# restore switches to original state
switches[0] ^= start_value
```